# Mongo DB factory always wires only one of the two configured mongo references

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have the below mongo configurations.

Config - 1:

```
<mongo:mongo replica-set="${system.mongo.host}" id="sysMongo">
        <mongo:options connections-per-host="8"
                   threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="2"
                   connect-timeout="2000"
                   max-wait-time="2000"
                   auto-connect-retry="true"  
                   socket-keep-alive="true"
                   socket-timeout="2000"
                   />
</mongo:mongo>


<mongo:db-factory id="system_MongoDbFactory" dbname="${system.mongo.database}" mongo-ref="sysMongo" username="${mongo.username}" password="${mongo.password}"/>
```

Config - 2:

```
<mongo:mongo replica-set="${mongo.host}" id="mongo">
        <mongo:options connections-per-host="8"
                   threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="2"
                   connect-timeout="1"
                   max-wait-time="1"
                   auto-connect-retry="true"  
                   socket-keep-alive="false"
                   socket-timeout="1"
                   />
</mongo:mongo>

<mongo:db-factory id="office_MongoDbFactory" dbname="${mongo.office.dbname}" mongo-ref="mongo" username="${mongo.username}" password="${mongo.password}"/>
```

If you see the above two configurations, two mongo instances are created with different IDs but still the configuration of only one of the instances is always wired to the mongo DB factory. In this case it is the bean 'sysMongo'. Both these configurations reside in the same application. Has anyone faced a similar problem. Any help in resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On digging further I figured that the mongo instances are different but they both share the same mongo options. I could not find a way to differentiate two instance of mongo options so far. I'm still analysing. In the meantime, if anyone has faced a similar issue and resolved the same please share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On doing further research I found that there is only one instance of Mongo Options created if configured through XML and it does not provide more flexibility on creating multiple instances. To create different instances we should have an implementation and use the builder class provided by mongo driver. Please find below the JIRA created and their resolution.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-999